# Python - Pygame Drawing Angle

Tags: python, geometry, pygame

I need to draw an angle(in Pygame), given it's
 1. Measure of the angle (θ)
 2. Endpoints of the base(A & B)

[image: Image showing A,B,C and θ]
**Here I know**
 1. Measure of θ (in radians and degrees)
 2. (x,y) of A and B
 3. Measure of BC
**My Question**
How do I calculate the position of the Co-ordinates(x,y) of point C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let BC be the length of the corresponding segment, theta be the angle in radians. Then compute the slope alpha of BC and then the coordinates of C like that:

```
alpha = atan2(A.y-B.y, A.x-B.x) - theta
C.x = B.x + BC * cos(alpha)
C.y = B.y + BC * sin(alpha)
```